# How to add search option in a listview with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I am trying to create a listview with name, checkbox and a SearchField on the top. After selecting an item and searching a new item, the previously checked position remains checked(position not the item). if the item selected is the first item in the list view let's say "apple" and when I enter keyword "bo" on the search field the list containing the substring "bo" appears but the first item on the list is already checked.

[Initially selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA0Wf.png)

[when I search a new item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Nwo.png)

in my Adapter

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(c,Country, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(((CheckBox)view).isChecked()) {
                    checkBoxState[position] = true;
                    items.add( nameTxt.getText().toString());


                    Log.d(String.valueOf(items),"abcd");
                }
                else {
                    checkBoxState[position] = false;
                    Log.d("VIVZ","checkbox1");
                    items.remove(nameTxt.getText().toString());
                }

            }
        });
```